# How to resolve the errors after running "mvn compile" on guava-libraries project?

Tags: maven, guava

I checked out guava-libraries and tried to build it with "mvn compile".

A mysterious error popped out and I failed to find a solution. But "mvn package" or "mvn install" succeeded without any errors.

Is 'compile' not a valid maven lifecycle for guava-libraries?

The core error message is below for your reference. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
[INFO] Unpacking /home/xxx/guava-libraries/guava/target/classes to /home/xxx/guava-libraries/guava-gwt/target/guava-sources with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.validate(AbstractUnArchiver.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractUnArchiver.extract(AbstractUnArchiver.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.unpack(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:258)
```

> Note: the paths in the error message are correct.

Comment: I work on Guava, and certainly I only use `mvn install`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ran into the bug [MDEP-98](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-98) of the maven-dependency-plugin, which is executed during the build of guava-gwt. Unfortunately, there is no solution to work around this bug, except not using `mvn compile` but `mvn package` or `mvn install` instead.